# How can I make vim-vmath work?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I installed [vim-vmath](https://github.com/nixon/vim-vmath) plugin using [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) and set the following maps to `~/.vimrc`

```
vmap <expr> ++ VMATH_YankAndAnalyse()
nmap        ++ vip++
```

Next, I issued these commands to check if everything was OK:

- `:echo loaded_vmath` gives me 1.
- `:scriptnames` includes `~/.vim/bundle/vim-vmath/plugin/vmath.vim`

But, when I open a new buffer and type in some numbers and use `++` in normal mode, it just says that it yanked the lines. Same if I do `vip++`. I never get the "summary row."

I tried removing all other plugins (in case they use the same mapping) that I have, but it didn't work.

I also tried it in vim and gvim.

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Update:
I even tried adding it to the system plugin directory. I have the same thing on my Windows gVim at work. I removed everything from my vimrc file except

```
set nocp
vmap <expr>  ++  VMATH_YankAndAnalyse()
nmap         ++  vip
```

and it still doesn't work

Comment: I just copied `vmath.vim` to `~/.vim/plugin` and it worked, how about you?

Comment: What does `:map` show you?

Comment: n ++ vip++ and v ++  VMATH_YankAndAnalyse(). I don't see any others mapped to ++. When I do the ++, it does the vip and says n lines yanked. I don't ever get the summary row. I do have several plugins installed that work fine. If I look at the resgister, the a,s,n,x ones are not set, so it obviously isn't actually calling the function, or it is failing in there. echoerr gives me nothing though (just learning here).